# Graphics interruption in monitor

Tags: display

A few days ago something strange has been happening with my monitor. After I start it on, a few minutes later, it's displays automatically get interrupted. Here are two pictures-

[image]
[image]

Please note that this is **not** an error in my graphics card, as my computer has none. When I start my computer, nothing happens. The error occurs a few minutes later. If I play a game or put activity on the monitor, it happens soon (within 5 minutes), but if I leave it still, it happens about a hour later. It doesn't work in safe mode either, something called  0x000000A appeas. Help is solicited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just be cause your computer does not have a discreet graphics card [does not mean you do not have a graphics processor](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_from_a_discrete_video_card_and_an_integrated_video_card).

Comment: So, what should I do? Should I change my graphics processor?

Comment: No, I doubt it that is the problem, but I just wanted to let you know (Also you can edit your comments for 5 minutes instead of posting new ones and cluttering up this section, you should combine those last two comments)

Comment: Okay, I've edited it (the first comment alone seems a bit rude :P). But is this problem a frequently experienced one (so there might exist a definite foolproof solution), or a rare one (that might be troublesome)?

Comment: Seems like it could be caused by overheating.

Comment: You can try adding a cheap graphics card & see if the problem resolves. The blue screen would indicate it's likely the graphics chipset on the motherboard, which you -might- be able to work around. But monitors also can cause this, minus the blue screen - it's dropping out of sync. Check also just visually that all fans on the motherboard are still working & free of dust clogs.

Comment: Also, I can't read the actual error in your screenshot, but fltmgr.sys is a Norton/Symantec component & often shows up in such failures. The actual error (few lines from the top) can indicate the type of failure & should be included in your question details, ie "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL", "BAD_POOL_CALLER" or whatever.

Comment: Actually that looks like the whole BSOD screen. If you look closely you can see the bezel of the monitor above that first sentence.

Snippet from here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000008e.htm

"If STOP error 0x0000008E is followed by 0xc0000005, as in STOP: 0x0000008E (0xc0000005, x, x, x), applying the latest Windows service pack will likely fix your issue."

Comment: @MichaelFrank I will be uploading a clearer screenshot soon. :)